# Which video formats are accetable?

Tags: html, video

I search in google and I didn't found.
I want to know, when I use input file like that:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*">
```

Which video formats can be uploaded?

I try to upload .flv & the browser ignore it.

Is there is any different  between browsers ? mobile browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form controls need a `name` attribute otherwise the form they're associated with ignores them:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" accept="video/*">
```

As for which video formats are allowed, it really depends on the OS and browser. For example, on my system (Window 10), Firefox preselects these extensions:

> *.avi;*.divx;*.flv;*.m4v;*.mkv;*.mov;*.mp4;*.mpeg;*.mpg;*.ogm;*.ogv;*.ogx;*.rm;*.rmvb;*.smil;*.webm;*.wmv;*.xvid

Comment: Form controls need a name only in a form... They can be unnamed orphans if you prefer to deal with the upload or whatever with js instead.

Comment: @Kaiido I believe the symptom described implies that this field is part of a form.